# How to load a grid into tkinter from file

Tags: python, list, tkinter

I am making a program similar to the memory game where i load a file and put it on a grid in tkinter.

I am currently having problems with this part of my code:

```
with open("Words.txt","r") as tenWordFile:
    for count in range(10):
        tenWordLine = tenWordFile.readline()
        tenWordLine = tenWordLine.strip("\n")
        Line = tenWordLine.split("\t")
        Words.append(Line[0])
        for r in range (3):
            for c in range (3):
                gridLabel = Label(app, text = Words (r,c),borderwidth = 1 ).grid(row=r,column=c)
        app.mainloop()
```

When i run my program i get an error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1487, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "E:\computer science\Controlled assessment 2\new cs.py", line 33, in tenWordGame
gridLabel = Label(app, text = Words (r,c),borderwidth = 1 ).grid(row=r,column=c)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I am looking for a solution to print out a 3x3 grid with random words from my words file.

Additionally, i am looking for a more pythonic way to this code aswell.

Lastly, thanks for reading and attempting to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Words` is a list. You can't call it like function using `()`. You have to use `[]` - `Words[some_index]` or `Words[some_index][other_index]` if it is two-dimensional list.

--

BTW: `gridLabel = Label(...).grid(...)` will assigns `None` to `gridLabel` because `grid(...)` always returns `None`.

If you don't need `gridLabel` in other part of code you can skip `gridLabel =`

```
Label(...).grid(...)
```

If you need `gridLabel` then do

```
gridLabel = Label(...)
gridLabel.grid(...)
```

Comment: thanks, although, what would i put in the [some_index] part?

Comment: probably `r` or `c` - you are author of this program ;)

Comment: any way i could add both r and c, because i can only add one, i tried it with both and got an error where python tells me that answer must be an integer not tuple.

Comment: I think you should first read all words from file and then create all labels. Now you read one line and then create all labels - or it is only wrong indentions.

Comment: you can't use tuple as list index. you could use `Words[(r*3)+c]` or something similar - but first you have to read all words from file.

Comment: how would i overcome the "list index out of range" error.

Comment: First you have to read all words from file. Now you read first line and start creating all labels - so you have not enough words to do this.

Comment: You can always use `print` to check what you have in variables. It can help to understand problem.